# How to get my Dao methods exposed in my Service layer?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

My Dao's are setup like:

```
UserDao
UserDaoImpl
```

My business layer are in service classes like:

```
UserService
UserServiceImpl
```

Now my Dao's have basic operations like get, update, save, etc.

I want to expose these methods in my service class without having to manually add these to each service interface.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The point of having services is to aggregate DAO methods within a transaction, and to add business logic. If all your services are doing is wrapping individual DAO methods there is no point to having them. Using some framework like Grails (or Play, so you can still use Java if you want) data access methods are added to your domain objects dynamically, you can call them from the controller and have a lot less CRUD code to mess with (but still have services as an option in the event you need them later).

Comment: agreed, but I will have business logic just maybe not for the basic get/update/delete methods, and I'll override when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If the service is doing nothing else besides CRUD operations, and no other service has need for that DAO, I'd see no reason why you can't just put those operations in the service implementation and dispense with the DAO.

It's easy enough to just use the service as a pass-through:

```
public interface FooService {
    Foo find(Long id); // Same as DAO signature
}

@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    @Resource(name = "fooRepository")
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    public Foo find(Long id) { return this.fooRepository.find(id); }
}
```

It's possible to write a generic DAO:

```
public interface GenericRepository<V, K extends Serializable> {
    V find(K key);
    List<V> find();
    K save(V value);
    void update(V value);
    void delete(V value);
}
```

Comment: yes but when I have 10 service classes it is allot of code to write, just hoping there was a way to get it for free using some OOP/generics somehow.

Comment: @codecompleting: Have a generic base class similar to the generic repository, and delegating to a generic DAO.

Comment: I have a generic repository, but the problem is I have to pass Class<T> type as a parameter when using hibernate. An example is here: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/source/browse/trunk/dao-hibernate/src/main/java/com/googlecode/genericdao/dao/hibernate/GeneralDAOImpl.java  I wish I didn't have to, maybe I can just have a private property in each Dao that sets the class type instead of having to have that as a parameter, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, I'd make it a private property and set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is kind of variation of Adapter pattern

You can also extend the UserDaoImpl to UserServiceImpl for example

```
UserServiceImpl extend UserDaoImpl implements UserService{
  // Rest of the Service implementation
  }
```

Comment: Concrete inheritance here?  Ugly.  Why not simply use delegation?

Comment: Yes we can have strategy pattern here

Comment: Strategy is implemented canonically as delegation and not inheritance.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: @Saish Agreed was only augmenting what you were saying about using delegation